# How can I recursively update all strings in a Go struct?

Tags: go, reflection

I want to recursively update all strings in a struct, including all strings in any slices in the struct.

I tried [this code](https://gist.github.com/anjankow/044ddcfcbf235eb75999588b2d7f7312) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71307631/8593689), but neither passed this unit test of mine:

```golang
func TestModifyStringsInStruct(t *testing.T) {
    type MyStruct struct {
        Field1         string
        Field2         int
        NestedStruct   *MyStruct
        SliceOfStrings []string
    }

    fn := func(s string) string {
        return "replacement_" + s
    }

    input := &MyStruct{
        Field1:         "abc",
        Field2:         42,
        NestedStruct:   &MyStruct{Field1: "def", Field2: 99},
        SliceOfStrings: []string{"foo", "bar", "baz"},
    }
    expected := &MyStruct{
        Field1:         "replacement_abc",
        Field2:         42,
        NestedStruct:   &MyStruct{Field1: "replacement_def", Field2: 99},
        SliceOfStrings: []string{"replacement_foo", "replacement_bar", "replacement_baz"},
    }

    err := UpdateStringValues(input, fn)
    assert.Assert(t, err == nil)
    assert.Equal(t, input.Field1, expected.Field1)
    assert.Equal(t, input.NestedStruct.Field1, expected.NestedStruct.Field1)
    assert.DeepEqual(t, input.SliceOfStrings, expected.SliceOfStrings)
}
```

I wrote this code, but it also fails my unit test:

```golang
func UpdateStringValues(structPtr interface{}, callback func(s string) string) error {
    // Verify if structPtr is a pointer to a struct
    inputParamStructType := reflect.TypeOf(structPtr)
    if inputParamStructType == nil ||
        inputParamStructType.Kind() != reflect.Ptr ||
        inputParamStructType.Elem().Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return errors.New("invalid input structPtr param: should be a pointer to a struct")
    }

    // ValueOf is used to get the struct data in the reflect.Value form
    structValue := reflect.ValueOf(structPtr)

    if structValue.CanSet() {
        return errors.New("struct values can't be changed")
    }

    // Elem is used to get the value pointed by the struct pointer
    structValue = structValue.Elem()

    // Update struct values, calling the callback on each string field
    return updateStringValues(&structValue, callback)
}

func updateStringValues(structValue *reflect.Value, callback func(s string) string) error {
    for i := 0; i < structValue.NumField(); i++ {
        field := structValue.Field(i)

        switch field.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct:
            if err := updateStringValues(&field, callback); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("field error: %s", err.Error())
            }
        case reflect.String:
            if field.CanSet() {
                field.SetString(callback(field.String()))
            }
        case reflect.Slice, reflect.Array:
            if err := updateStringValuesList(&field, callback); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("field error: %s", err.Error())
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func updateStringValuesList(listValue *reflect.Value, callback func(s string) string) error {
    for i := 0; i < listValue.Len(); i++ {
        elem := listValue.Index(i)

        switch elem.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct:
            if err := updateStringValues(&elem, callback); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("field error: %s", err.Error())
            }
        case reflect.String:
            if elem.CanSet() {
                elem.SetString(callback(elem.String()))
            }
        case reflect.Slice, reflect.Array:
            if err := updateStringValuesList(&elem, callback); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("field error: %s", err.Error())
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

How can I correctly recursively update all strings in a struct, including all strings in any slices in the struct?

Comment: You need to handle `case reflect.Pointer`

Comment: @dave I wrote the answer based your advice. Please check it if you can spare time. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Summary

As @dave said, we need to handle the case where the field type is pointer.

So, `updateStringValues` function should be like this.

It is important to consider the case where the pointer field can be `nil`

I checked this code is working well at https://go.dev/play/p/y03ZFxzrGyk

```
func updateStringValues(structValue *reflect.Value, callback func(s string) string) error {
    for i := 0; i < structValue.NumField(); i++ {
        field := structValue.Field(i)

        switch field.Kind() {
        case reflect.Ptr:
            if field.IsNil() {
                continue
            }
            elem := field.Elem()
            if err := updateStringValues(&elem, callback); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("field error: %s", err.Error())
            }
        case reflect.Struct:
            if err := updateStringValues(&field, callback); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("field error: %s", err.Error())
            }
        case reflect.String:
            if field.CanSet() {
                field.SetString(callback(field.String()))
            }
        case reflect.Slice, reflect.Array:
            if err := updateStringValuesList(&field, callback); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("field error: %s", err.Error())
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

#### In detail

I double checked the dave's comment by adding the Print line at `updateStringValues`. There was the unhandled field `*reflectingtest.MyStruct`

```
0  field type is  string
1  field type is  int
2  field type is  *reflectingtest.MyStruct
3  field type is  []string
```

So we need to handle this. I made this code at `updateStringValues`

```
        case reflect.Ptr:
            if field.IsNil() {
                continue
            }
            elem := field.Elem()
            if err := updateStringValues(&elem, callback); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("field error: %s", err.Error())
            }
```

First, I thought it can be `nil`. So I added the code handling the `nil`

For accessing(modifying) the members of the struct and iterating them, I thought we need to use `Elem()`

And then I thought we need to pass it as a pointer, for calling by reference.

#### Reference

I referred this pages for understanding `reflect` concretely

- https://go.dev/blog/laws-of-reflection
- [What is the difference between reflect.ValueOf() and Value.Elem() in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57388657/what-is-the-difference-between-reflect-valueof-and-value-elem-in-go)